# How much power does a motherboard in laptops consume and which type of motherboard (ITX or ATX) is installed in laptops?

Tags: motherboard, power-consumption

I was not able to find that information online. I saw that for desktops the power consumption does not go over 100W.

Comment: Depends on the laptop, I bet some big gaming laptops go over 100W

Answer (score 3):

Laptops always have custom motherboards that do NOT adhere to ITX or ATX standards.
Those just wouldn't fit.
In design they are (usually) conceptually close to ITX, but the form-factor is completely determined by the available space in the laptop casing.

Power-requirements are purely determined by the specs and use of the computer. That goes for any computer, not just laptops. There is even no such thing as a well-defined criteria what constitutes power-requirement for a motherboard. Do you count power consumed by RAM memory as "motherboard" or RAM? What about Nvme SSD? Mini-PCI Wifi adapter? USB devices without powered hub? These are directly powered by the motherboard, but are not part of it.

Comment: Due to the evolution of the “laptop” there isn’t a standard motherboard form factor.  There are similarities and certainly limitations of any device, but there are laptops, that literally use desktop parts.